# Validate apex interactive grid records even if no record is edited

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to validate apex interactive grid records even if no record is edited or inserted before page submit.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no update/insert or any edit of Interactive Grid region. Do you really have to check Interactive Grid? Are you sure that checking the rows in table/database is not enough? You can use simple pl/sql or sql validation. And check the data in table you are using in Interactive Grid.

Simply create new validation and write a query that will fail if it will return rows. Edit the error message and it is done. It will fire every time before submit page.

[image]